# Configure XQuartz to use second screen

Tags: macos, xorg, xquartz

Is it possible to configure XQuartz to use my second screen? I've tried updating the default DISPLAY variable to something like `/tmp/launch-oEIGJf/org.macosforge.xquartz:0.1`, but this (kind of obviously) won't work. Perhaps there is a configuration file somewhere that specifies the "normal" DISPAY variable?

Using OS X 10.8.5 and XQuartz 2.7.5